# Change the column order in a CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am playing around with CSS grids.

When I view it on a desktop size `(min-width: 769px)`, I have a single row with three columns. Something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
|   col 1     |         col 2       | col 3 |
|             |                     |       |
---------------------------------------------
```

Can I move the columns around with css-grid so I can do something like the following on a mobile layout?

```
---------------------------------------------
|     col 1             |      col 3        |
|                       |                   |
---------------------------------------------
|                     col 2                 |
---------------------------------------------
```

I know I span cells with something like this:

```css
.content {
  grid-column: 1 / span2;
}
```

**But I want to change the order of the columns. Can I do that without a pre-processor?**

Here is my current grid class:

```css
.my-grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 25%;
   grid-template-rows: 1fr; /* For as many rows as you need */
   grid-gap: 10px;
   border: 2px solid #222;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: CSS Grid seems to support `order` as used in flexbox. https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example23/

Comment: Yes that works, was having trouble with column span, but worked that out now as well.

Comment: Cool. I'm not overly familiar with grid so couldn't help more..

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Grid Layout provides multiple methods for re-arranging grid items. I've listed four below.

1. The **`grid-template-areas`** property
2. Line-based placement
3. The **`order`** property
4. The **`dense`** function of the `grid-auto-flow` property. *(Possibly the simplest, easiest and most robust solution for this type of layout, as it works for any number of grid items.)*

---

Here's the original layout:

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 25%;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* for demo */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
grid-item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>1</grid-item>
  <grid-item>2</grid-item>
  <grid-item>3</grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

[**jsFiddle demo 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/3mke2k69/5/)

---

### 1. The `grid-template-areas` property

The `grid-template-areas` property allows you to arrange your layout using ASCII visual art.

Place the grid area names (which are defined for each element) in the position where you want them to appear.

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 25%;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* for demo */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "column-1 column-2 column-3";
}

grid-item:nth-child(1) { grid-area: column-1; }
grid-item:nth-child(2) { grid-area: column-2; }
grid-item:nth-child(3) { grid-area: column-3; }

@media ( max-width: 500px ) {  
  grid-container { 
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
        grid-template-areas: " column-1 column-3 " 
                             " column-2 column-2 ";
   }
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
grid-item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>1</grid-item>
  <grid-item>2</grid-item>
  <grid-item>3</grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

[**jsFiddle demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/3mke2k69/6/)

*From the specification:*

> [**7.3. Named Areas: the `grid-template-areas`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-template-areas-property)
>
> This property specifies ***named grid areas***, which are not
>   associated with any particular grid item, but can be referenced from
>   the grid-placement properties.
>
> The syntax of the `grid-template-areas` property also provides a
>   visualization of the structure of the grid, making the overall layout
>   of the grid container easier to understand.
>
> All strings must have the same number of columns, or else the declaration is invalid.
>
> If a named grid area spans multiple grid cells, but those cells do not form a single filled-in rectangle, the declaration is invalid.
>
> *Note: Non-rectangular or disconnected regions may be permitted in a future version of this module.*

---

### 2. Line-based Placement

Use `grid-row-start`, `grid-row-end`, `grid-column-start`, `grid-column-end`, or their shorthands, `grid-row` and `grid-column`, to set a grid item's size and location in the grid.

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 25%;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* for demo */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

@media ( max-width: 500px ) {  
  grid-container         { grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  }
  grid-item:nth-child(1) { grid-row: 1 / 2; grid-column: 1 / 2; }
  grid-item:nth-child(2) { grid-row: 2 / 3; grid-column: 1 / 3; }
  grid-item:nth-child(3) { grid-row: 1 / 2; grid-column: 2 / 3; }
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
grid-item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>1</grid-item>
  <grid-item>2</grid-item>
  <grid-item>3</grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

[**jsFiddle demo 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/3mke2k69/7/)

*From the specification:*

> [**8.3. Line-based Placement: the `grid-row-start`, `grid-column-start`, `grid-row-end`, and `grid-column-end` properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement)

---

### 3. The `order` property

The `order` property in Grid Layout does the same as in Flex Layout.

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 25%;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* for demo */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

@media ( max-width: 500px ) {  
  grid-container         { grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  }
  grid-item:nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
  grid-item:nth-child(2) { order: 3; grid-column: 1 / 3; }
  grid-item:nth-child(3) { order: 2; }
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
grid-item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>1</grid-item>
  <grid-item>2</grid-item>
  <grid-item>3</grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

[**jsFiddle demo 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/3mke2k69/8/)

*From the specification:*

> [**6.3. Reordered Grid Items: the `order` property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#order-property)

---

### 4. The `dense` function of the `grid-auto-flow` property

This solution is possibly the simplest, easiest and most robust of all presented here, as it works for any number of grid items.

Although this solution doesn't provide any major advantage over the previous three *in the layout described in the question*, which consists of only three grid items, it offers huge benefits when the number of grid items is higher or dynamically-generated.

This question and the solutions above address this:

```
01  03
02  02
```

But let's say we need this:

```
01  03
02  02

04  06
05  05

07  09
08  08

10  12
11  11

and so on...
```

Using `grid-template-areas`, line-based placement and `order`, the solution would require a lot of hard-coding (if we knew the number of total items) and maybe CSS custom properties and/or JavaScript (if the items were generated dynamically).

The **`dense`** function of CSS Grid, however, can handle both scenarios simply and easily.

By applying `grid-auto-flow: dense` to the container, each third item will backfill the empty cell created as a result of consecutive ordering.

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 25%;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;     /* KEY RULE; deactive to see what happens without it;
                                  defaults to "sparse" (consecutive ordering) value */
  }
  grid-item:nth-child(3n + 2) {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
grid-item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
grid-item:nth-child(-n + 3)                    { background-color: aqua; }
grid-item:nth-child(n + 4):nth-child(-n + 6)   { background-color: lightgreen; }
grid-item:nth-child(n + 7):nth-child(-n + 9)   { background-color: orange; }
grid-item:nth-child(n + 10):nth-child(-n + 12) { background-color: lightgray; }
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>1</grid-item>
  <grid-item>2</grid-item>
  <grid-item>3</grid-item>
  <grid-item>4</grid-item>
  <grid-item>5</grid-item>
  <grid-item>6</grid-item>
  <grid-item>7</grid-item>
  <grid-item>8</grid-item>
  <grid-item>9</grid-item>
  <grid-item>10</grid-item>
  <grid-item>11</grid-item>
  <grid-item>12</grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

[**jsFiddle demo 4**](https://jsfiddle.net/29oa3jds/)

*From the specification:*

> [**§7.7. Automatic Placement: the `grid-auto-flow` property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property)
>
> ***dense***
>
> If specified, the auto-placement algorithm uses a “dense” packing
>   algorithm, which attempts to fill in holes earlier in the grid if
>   smaller items come up later.
>
> If omitted, a “sparse” algorithm is used, where the placement
>   algorithm only ever moves “forward” in the grid when placing items,
>   never backtracking to fill holes.