# How to set a pattern for re-ordering a variable number of grid items?

Tags: css, css-grid

This is a bit of a "follow up" question on [Change the column order in a css grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367864/change-the-column-order-in-a-css-grid)

In that question a solution is given for ordering the cells of a grid when using a smaller screen. It works, however it's not "extendible": as in it only works on a grid with a predefined number of rows. The solution as given per above question:

> ### 3. `order`
>
> The `order` property in Grid Layout does the same as in Flex Layout.
>
> ```css
>  
>  grid-container {
>    display: grid;
>    grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 25%;
>    grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* for demo */
>    grid-gap: 10px;
>  }
>  
>  @media ( max-width: 500px ) {  
>    grid-container         { grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  }
>    grid-item:nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
>    grid-item:nth-child(2) { order: 3; grid-column: 1 / 3; }
>    grid-item:nth-child(3) { order: 2; }
>  }
>  
>  /* non-essential decorative styles */
>  grid-item {
>    border: 1px solid gray;
>    background-color: lightgreen;
>    display: flex;
>    align-items: center;
>    justify-content: center;
>  }
>  grid-item:nth-child(2) {
>    background-color: orange;
>  }
> ```
>
> ```html
>  
>  <grid-container>
>    <grid-item>1</grid-item>
>    <grid-item>2</grid-item>
>    <grid-item>3</grid-item>
>  </grid-container>
> ```

[**jsFiddle demo 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/3mke2k69/8/)

In our application the number of "rows" is not given and can be more. The test is:

```css
 grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 25%;
   grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* for demo */
   grid-gap: 10px;
 }

 @media ( max-width: 500px ) {  
   grid-container         { grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  }
   grid-item:nth-child(3n-2) { order: 1; }
   grid-item:nth-child(3n-1) { order: 3; grid-column: 1 / 3; }
   grid-item:nth-child(3n) { order: 2; }
 }

 /* non-essential decorative styles */
 grid-item {
   border: 1px solid gray;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
 }
 grid-item:nth-child(3n-1) {
   background-color: orange;
 }
```

```html
 <grid-container>
   <grid-item>1</grid-item>
   <grid-item>2</grid-item>
   <grid-item>3</grid-item>
   <grid-item>4</grid-item>
   <grid-item>5</grid-item>
   <grid-item>6</grid-item>
   <grid-item>7</grid-item>
   <grid-item>8</grid-item>
   <grid-item>9</grid-item>
   <!-- etc -->
 </grid-container>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mke2k69/7/)

As one can quickly see the orders makes all "2nd" cells (2, 5, 8...) all the way to the bottom instead of keeping each group of 3. In a simple ascii art I'd like:

```
c1 c3
c2 c2
c4 c6
c5 c5
c7 c9
c8 c8
```

(How) can this be done?

Comment: I deleted my answer below and posted the solution as a fourth method in my answer referenced in your question.