# Toggle grid position on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to create a grid with two columns and when the mouse hovers on the background, I want the background to change position from it's original position to the other position.
Here is what I have so far...

```css
.page-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.bg-container {
  background-color: brown;
}

.bg-container:hover {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.login-container {}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="bg-container">

  </div>
  <div class="login-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to apply a translate animation while it moves, how can I achieve this.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367864/change-the-column-order-in-a-css-grid

Comment: I have looked into it, it is not what I'm  looking for. @DeepakS.M

Comment: You can't animate a change of background between two separate elements, nor can you animate a change in grid layout.

Comment: Hacky but perhaps what you are looking for - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZEpVjKq?editors=1100

Comment: I got something to work based on your comment. make it an answer so I can accept it. @Paulie_D