# CSS Grid: Switch two specific columns order

Tags: css, css-grid

I would like to switch the 3rd and 4th column of my grid on desktop.

I know that I could assign grid-order to each item or use a own row for two of the divs and then set the order, but I would like to avoid both to reduce code.

Is there any way to achieve this with css-grid? I am open for solutions via css-flex, if that would be easier.

My current code looks like this:

```css
.row{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
  }
}

.row div{border:1px solid black}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
      <div>[IMG]</div>
      <div>Text</div>
      <div>[IMG]</div>
      <div>Text</div>
      <div>[IMG]</div>
      <div>Text</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367864/change-the-column-order-in-a-css-grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property with a flex or grid container. If you don't want to use `order`, you can play with `grid-column` and `grid-row` like below.

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
  }
  .row>div:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  .row>div:nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
  }
}

.row div {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>[IMG]</div>
  <div>Text</div>
  <div style="background: red">[IMG]</div>
  <div style="background: yellow">Text</div>
  <div>[IMG]</div>
  <div>Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm. I need to wait a bit longer to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like below

```css
.row{
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row div:nth-child(3) {
     grid-column:2;
  }
}

.row div{border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div>[IMG]</div>
      <div>Text</div>
      <div>[IMG]</div>
      <div>Text</div>
      <div>[IMG]</div>
      <div>Text</div>
  </div>
```