# Bootstrap grid system 1 row with two columns into 2 rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-grid

So I have this layout on my grid
[image]

But as the width goes smaller I want to change to this layout
[image]

So far I have it like this

```css
.row > div {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class='row'>
      <div class="col-md-12">
      2
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
      3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367864/change-the-column-order-in-a-css-grid

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      1
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class='row'>
         <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
            2
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            3
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think best practice way CSS Grid layout to essay and customizable

```css
.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .one {
    grid-row: 1/3;
  }
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .three {
    grid-column: 2/3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>

  <div class="one">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="two">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    3
  </div>

</div>
```