# Why are the slides of my carousel not changing when the buttons are clicked?

Tags: html, css

I found a carousel on internet made from HTML and CSS and copy pasted it into my website code. The code i found had the code for the buttons written before the code of carousel  that's why the buttons were showing at the top of carousel. I corrected the layout but for some reason the buttons stopped working.

```css
.products {
  grid-template-rows: 500px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}

.rbn {
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.images {
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
  max-height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

main#carousel {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  padding-right: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
  --items: 8;
  --middle: 3;
  --position: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: coral;
  --r: calc(var(--position) - var(--offset));
  --abs: max(calc(var(--r) * -1), var(--r));
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transform: rotateY(calc(-10deg * var(--r))) translateX(calc(-300px * var(--r)));
  z-index: calc((var(--position) - var(--abs)));
}

div.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  --offset: 1;
  background-color: #90f1ef;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  --offset: 2;
  background-color: #ff70a6;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  --offset: 3;
  background-color: #ff9770;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(4) {
  --offset: 4;
  background-color: #ffd670;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(5) {
  --offset: 5;
  background-color: #e9ff70;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(6) {
  --offset: 6;
  background-color: #f76e11;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(7) {
  --offset: 7;
  background-color: #2eb086;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(8) {
  --offset: 8;
  background-color: #faeee7;
}

input:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(1):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 1;
}

input:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(2):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 2;
}

input:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 4 /5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(3):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(4):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 4;
}

input:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-column: 6 / 7;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(5):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 5;
}

input:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-column: 7 / 8;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(6):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 6;
}

input:nth-of-type(7) {
  grid-column: 8 / 9;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(7):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 7;
}

input:nth-of-type(8) {
  grid-column: 9 / 10;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(8):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 8;
}
```

```html
<div "products">
  <main id="carousel">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="almondflakes.png" alt="af" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="butterscotchballs.png" alt="bb" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="chocoballs.png" alt="cb" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="chocolatesprinklers.png" alt="cs" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="oreodust.png" alt="od" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="rainbowsprinkles.png" alt="rs" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="ricekrispies.png" alt="rk" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="whitecreamballs.png" alt="wc" />
    </div>
  </main>
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" checked />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The tilde (`~`) in your CSS is a [subsequent sibling combination selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators). When you reversed the structure of your HTML you broke those. They don't work in reverse.

You'll need to use another means of relocating the buttons that doesn't involve changing the markup. [Reversing column order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367864/change-the-column-order-in-a-css-grid) might do.

```css
.products {
  grid-template-rows: 500px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}

.rbn {
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.images {
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
  max-height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

main#carousel {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  padding-right: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
  --items: 8;
  --middle: 3;
  --position: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: coral;
  --r: calc(var(--position) - var(--offset));
  --abs: max(calc(var(--r) * -1), var(--r));
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transform: rotateY(calc(-10deg * var(--r))) translateX(calc(-300px * var(--r)));
  z-index: calc((var(--position) - var(--abs)));
}

div.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  --offset: 1;
  background-color: #90f1ef;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  --offset: 2;
  background-color: #ff70a6;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  --offset: 3;
  background-color: #ff9770;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(4) {
  --offset: 4;
  background-color: #ffd670;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(5) {
  --offset: 5;
  background-color: #e9ff70;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(6) {
  --offset: 6;
  background-color: #f76e11;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(7) {
  --offset: 7;
  background-color: #2eb086;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(8) {
  --offset: 8;
  background-color: #faeee7;
}

input:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(1):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 1;
}

input:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(2):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 2;
}

input:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 4 /5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(3):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(4):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 4;
}

input:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-column: 6 / 7;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(5):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 5;
}

input:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-column: 7 / 8;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(6):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 6;
}

input:nth-of-type(7) {
  grid-column: 8 / 9;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(7):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 7;
}

input:nth-of-type(8) {
  grid-column: 9 / 10;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(8):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 8;
}
```

```html
<div "products">
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" checked />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />
  <input class="rbn" type="radio" name="position" />

  <main id="carousel">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="almondflakes.png" alt="af" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="butterscotchballs.png" alt="bb" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="chocoballs.png" alt="cb" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="chocolatesprinklers.png" alt="cs" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="oreodust.png" alt="od" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="rainbowsprinkles.png" alt="rs" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="ricekrispies.png" alt="rk" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="images" src="whitecreamballs.png" alt="wc" />
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```